# genymotion samsung s3 very slow

Tags: android, performance, amazon-s3, emulation, genymotion

I'm trying to load a Samsung s3 api under Genymotion but it never finishes. I turn it off after half an hour.  I tried a fresh download of the VM but no difference.

I have 4gig ram plenty free and 64bit dual core. 
Samsung s and s2 launch in seconds.

Is S3 just more demanding?